# Stop embedded SVGs from capturing mouse events on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg, pointer-events

Pretty straightforward. I have an SVG embedded in my document through `<object>` and I'm applying `pointer-events:none` in the style at the root `<svg>`. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome (I'm not interested in any other browsers at the moment)

## MWE

Have an HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Why you no fix, Chrome?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="click"><object data="svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object></a>
    <script>document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click',e => console.log(e));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Have an SVG file

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="pointer-events:none">
    <path fill="#4a90d6" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#222222" stroke-width="2" d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 50 100 z" />
</svg>
```

If there is no way to allow the event to bubble up to the anchor (ie: stop svg from capturing), then a way to pass an event through the event horizon would also be nice

## EDIT

I forgot to add that the `<object>` element has to remain clickable. And I emphasize that the MWE works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Comment: Can you not use an <img> tag instead of an <object> tag as that won't be interactive which is what you want in this case?

Comment: No. I need to programmatically (sp?) access some svg properties. `<img>` tags make such requirements unfulfillable

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to put the SVG inline then in order to get round the Chrome issue.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<object style="pointer-events:none" ... >
```

that should do the trick ;-)

Comment: right.... but now I can't click on `<object>` which is where most of my events are attached. An *A* for effort though

Comment: I thought about it but it's impractical in my current situation. It is a pretty good idea ^^